# get 'xxx is not a known element' error in my angular storybook

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I imported my CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in my app modules and use it in my stories. If I open storybook and try to get accesss to a component whichone uses some elemts from the libary I got the following Error:

[image]

Is there a way to also apply the custom_elements_schema to storybook ?